# getting property from ElementHandle

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer in a Node.js module. I retrieve an HTML element with an XPath selector and need to extract the text property.

Currently I use:

```js
    // Get the element
    let ele = await element.$x(`//div[@class="g"][${i}]/div/div/h3/a`);

    // Get the text property
    const title = await(await ele[0].getProperty('text')).jsonValue();
```

Is there any way to do this without being so verbose?

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree that this way of getting the text property is as ugly as hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use the `eval()` function so I can use less verbose code:

```
page.eval(() => {

    let element = document.querySelector('#mySelector')
    return element.innerText

}).then(text => {
    console.log(text)
})
```

You can also pass an element you previously grabbed like your `ele` var:

**Using Promise syntax**

```
page.eval(element => {
    return element.innerText
}, ele).then(text => {
    // Do whatever you want with text
})
```

**Using async/await syntax**

```
const text = await page.eval(element => element.innerText), ele) 
// Do whatever you want with text
```

Comment: `TypeError: page.eval is not a function`. Did you mean `page.evaluate()`? You can call `evaluate` on the handle directly: `someHandle.evaluate(el => el.innerText)` to avoid having to pass it as a second parameter.

Answer (score 9):

...or write a tiny helper function.

```
public async GetProperty(element: ElementHandle, property: string): Promise<string> {
    return await (await element.getProperty(property)).jsonValue();
}
```

use:

```
let inner = await GetProperty(ele, 'innerHTML');
```

Answer (score 4):

I would rather extend ElementHandle for missing methods like:

```
//  puppeteer@1.9.0
let { ElementHandle } = require( "puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext" );
// puppeteer@1.12 
if ( ElementHandle === undefined ) {
  ElementHandle = require( "puppeteer/lib/JSHandle" ).ElementHandle;
}

/**
 * Set value on a select element
 * @param {string} value
 * @returns {Promise<Undefined>}
 */
ElementHandle.prototype.select = async function( value ) {
  await this._page.evaluateHandle( ( el, value ) => {
      const event = new Event( "change", { bubbles: true });
      event.simulated = true;
      el.querySelector( `option[value="${ value }"]` ).selected = true;
      el.dispatchEvent( event );
  }, this, value );
};

/**
 * Check if element is visible in the DOM
 * @returns {Promise<Boolean>}
 **/
ElementHandle.prototype.isVisible = async function(){
  return (await this.boundingBox() !== null);
};

/**
 * Get element attribute
 * @param {string} attr
 * @returns {Promise<String>}
 */
ElementHandle.prototype.getAttr = async function( attr ){
  const handle = await this._page.evaluateHandle( ( el, attr ) => el.getAttribute( attr ), this, attr );
  return await handle.jsonValue();
};

/**
 * Get element property
 * @param {string} prop
 * @returns {Promise<String>}
 */
ElementHandle.prototype.getProp = async function( prop ){
  const handle = await this._page.evaluateHandle( ( el, prop ) => el[ prop ], this, prop );
  return await handle.jsonValue();
};
```

As soon as you import this module once in you code you can play with the handles as follows:

```
const elh = await page.$( `#testTarget` );
console.log( await elh.isVisible() );
console.log( await elh.getAttr( "class" ) );
console.log( await elh.getProp( "innerHTML" ) );
```

Comment: I needed to changed the first line to const ElementHandle = require( "puppeteer/lib/ElementHandle" ).ElementHandle; for node v8 & latest puppeteer

Comment: Wow!! That is beautiful. Thank you so much for this wonderful answer. 
I don't understand, One would imaging that the ElementHandle and the JSHandle objects have simpler API to work with them! I don't know, maybe that's in the works for them.

Comment: This kinda worked for me but it broke some other part of my code base which also depended on Puppeteer.. :(

Once I include this I am getting errors


`const ElementHandle = require( "puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/JSHandle" ).ElementHandle;`

Answer (score 3):

In the accepted answer `page.eval()` is mentioned, however, with puppeteer such a method has never existed and I think what is really meant is in fact [page.evaluate()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

However, Using `page.evaluate()` requires you to split your operation into two parts (one for getting the element, one to select the value).

> Is there any way to do this not as verbose?

In such cases, [page.$eval()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) appears to be more appropriate as it allows you to directly pass your selector as argument, thus reducing the number of operations or variable you need to introduce:

Now in your particular case, you want to perform the `$eval` not just on the whole page but on an `ElementHandle`, which is possible since [May 9, 2018](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) via [elementHandle.$eval()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args-1):

> This method runs document.querySelector within the element and passes it as the first argument to pageFunction.

[image]

This translates to your example as follows (here using a css selector instead of xpath):

```
await elementHandle.$eval('/div/div/h3/a', el => el.text);
```

Comment: @luwes, I didn't write the selector, I merely took it from the OP to match the example provided in the OP. The point of my answer is not the selector but the mentioning of `$eval` Therefore, please consider removing your downvote.

Comment: I would remove the downvote but seems it's locked now, sorry about that.
Just I tried the code above and it didn't work, just wanted other people know that the code is not correct as xpath is not the same as an element/css selector.

Comment: Hi @luwes, okay, no worries, your remark about the xpath is actually correct and I therefore changed my example code to a css selector. I think removing the downvote now should work after the edit. if not, doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 0):

My way

```
async function getVisibleHandle(selector, page) {

    const elements = await page.$$(selector);

    let hasVisibleElement = false,
        visibleElement = '';

    if (!elements.length) {
        return [hasVisibleElement, visibleElement];
    }

    let i = 0;
    for (let element of elements) {
        const isVisibleHandle = await page.evaluateHandle((e) => {
            const style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
            return (style && style.display !== 'none' &&
                style.visibility !== 'hidden' && style.opacity !== '0');
        }, element);
        var visible = await isVisibleHandle.jsonValue();
        const box = await element.boxModel();
        if (visible && box) {
            hasVisibleElement = true;
            visibleElement = elements[i];
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return [hasVisibleElement, visibleElement];
}
```

Usage

```
let selector = "a[href='https://example.com/']";

let visibleHandle = await getVisibleHandle(selector, page);

if (visibleHandle[1]) {

   await Promise.all([
     visibleHandle[1].click(),
     page.waitForNavigation()
   ]);
}
```